# Matching Values to Dataframe based on the Values of 2 Columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I made a new empty column in my dataframe and I want to match values from a separate dataframe to rows with the same individual and year.

```
df1 <- data.frame(names = c("greg", "naomi", "tera", "greg", "dylan", "tera"),
                  year = c(2010, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2013), status = numeric())

df2 <- data.frame(names = c("greg", "greg", "naomi", "tera", "tera", "dylan"),
year = c(2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2013, 2012),
status = c(1,0,2,0,1,3))
```

I want the values from df2$status to be matched to the corresponding year and individual in df1, as seen below.

```
names year status
1  greg 2010      1
2 naomi 2010      2
3  tera 2011      0
4  greg 2012      0
5 dylan 2013      3
6  tera 2013      1
```

I've considered using `if... else` but I want to know if there's a way to use the `match()` function or something else along those lines. I'm trying to keep my code as short as I can.

Comment: Your examples are throwing errors `Error in data.frame(names = c("greg", "naomi", "tera", "greg", "dylan",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 0`

Answer (score 2):

We can use a join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, status := i.status, on = .(names, year)]
```

Comment: is `i.status` referring to the status column in df1 or df2?

Comment: @user13822027  I see that you have created a  column with 0 values with 'status' for 'df1'.  If same column names are present, `i.status` refers to the one in 'df2'.  If there is only a single column and that is in 'df2', you can refer as `status` alone